# Creating native thread on windows running MRI

Tags: ruby, windows, multithreading

Can I create a native thread on Windows running MRI, using the [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) API call and the [win32-api](https://github.com/djberg96/win32-api), [windows-api](https://github.com/djberg96/windows-api) and [windows-pr](https://github.com/djberg96/windows-pr) gems?
If so, can someone give me an example? Would that thread work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's not possible.
I ended up using [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) to handle multiple I/O events on the same thread.